# Is there a valid usecase for redefining "define" in scheme/racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, language-features

I'm playing around with racket/scheme and it allows me to redefine for instance `define` and bind it as a value.

```
> (define define 2)
> define
2
```

In that scope I can no longer define anything using `define` since it is obviously bound to 2. This works for all "keywords" I tried it with (`if`, `cond` etc.).

However it is not possible to use `define` to specify my own definition function:

```
> (define mydef define)
stdin::14: define: not allowed in an expression context in: define

 === context ===
/usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/norm-define.rkt:8:4: normalize-definition
/usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/kw.rkt:796:2
/usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

I suppose there is another means of extending the language in racket to add my own definition function should I want to, but why is this way disallowed?

This does leave me wondering if there is any valid use case at all for redefining `define`? I realize that this is a bit opinion based, but I'm looking for use cases where this *might* be a justified thing to do (whether it is or not, is another matter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you might actually want to extend the `define` form to provide capabilities that the standard `define` doesn't. An example is providing decorators (thanks to uselpa's answer for inspiration):

```
(require (only-in racket/base (define basic-define)))

(define-syntax wrap-decorators
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ () value)
     value)
    ((_ (decorator next ...) value)
     (decorator (wrap-decorators (next ...) value)))))

(define-syntax define
  (syntax-rules (@)
    ((_ (@ decorator ...) (id . params) body ...)
     (define (@ decorator ...) id (lambda params body ...)))
    ((_ (@ decorator ...) id value)
     (define id (wrap-decorators (decorator ...) value)))
    ((_ other ...)
     (basic-define other ...))))

(define (trace label)
  (lambda (f)
    (lambda args
      (dynamic-wind (thunk (eprintf "enter ~a: ~s~%" label args))
                    (thunk (apply f args))
                    (thunk (eprintf "exit ~a: ~s~%" label args))))))
```

Now you can use it this way:

```
(define (@ (trace 'hypot)) (hypot x y)
  (sqrt (+ (sqr x) (sqr y))))
```

This causes the `hypot` function to be wrapped with `trace` so when you call it, tracing happens:

```
> (hypot 3 4)
enter hypot: (3 4)
exit hypot: (3 4)
5
```

Or, using uselpa's `memoize` function, you can use:

```
(define (@ memoize) (fib n)
  (if (< n 2)
      n
      (+ (fib (sub1 n)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

and get a speedy memoised `fib` function. You can even trace and memoise it, showing only the actual (cache miss) invocations:

```
(define (@ (trace 'fib) memoize) (fib n)
  (if (< n 2)
      n
      (+ (fib (sub1 n)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

Notice, in my macro, that I imported Racket's `define` as `basic-define`, so that my redefined `define` could delegate to it.

Comment: So the benefit here is that I can alter the syntax for a `define` adding things such as decorators? And the reason why `define` is not a regular function I suppose is because it shouldn't be evaluated as other functions (i.e. the "arguments" to `define` should not be evaluated)?

Comment: The general concept in Scheme is that: 1. redefinitions affect your current module only, and are not global (though you can export your redefinitions for other modules to import), and thus 2. there is no need for reserved words, and everything can be redefined. Being able to augment built-in functionality is certainly a nice feature, but not the reason per se for being able to redefine `define`, `if`, etc., but simply a result of nothing being reserved, because nothing needs to be reserved.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to bind the original `define` to a different symbol, you can:

```
#lang racket

(require (rename-in racket (define mydef)))

(mydef n 2)
(mydef (times2 n) (* 2 n))

(times2 n)
=> 4
```

Now *can* redefine `define`, but depending on what you're up to it's more likely you would end up defining it as a *macro* rather than a function. Inside your `define` macro (or function) you can still use the orginial `define` which is now bound to `mydef`.

Redefining `define` can make sense in some contexts. An *alternative* could be to work with something akin to a Python *decorator*. Here's an example for memoisation. Assuming this procedure:

```
(define (memoize fn)
  (let ((cache (make-hash)))
    (λ arg (hash-ref! cache arg (thunk (apply fn arg))))))
```

and a classical Fibonacci procedure:

```
(define fib 
  (lambda (n)
    (if (< n 2) n (+ (fib (sub1 n)) (fib (- n 2))))))    

(time (fib 35))
cpu time: 3039 real time: 3036 gc time: 0
9227465
```

can be rewritten

```
(define fib
  (memoize
   (lambda (n)
     (if (< n 2) n (+ (fib (sub1 n)) (fib (- n 2)))))))

(time (fib 35))
cpu time: 1 real time: 0 gc time: 0
9227465
```

Comment: Thanks for providing decorators as an inspiration for redefining `define`. With my `define`, you can simply use `(define (@ memoize) (fib n) ...)` and it will be memoised for you. :-D

Answer (score 4):

The other two answers have already provided excellent explanations, so I'll just add a more Racket-specific example.

In Racket, you can build your own `#lang` that treats definitions differently than the base Racket language. For example, Typed Racket's definition form allows code that looks like this:

```
(define (fact [n : Integer]) : Integer
  (if (zero? n)
      1
      (* n (fact (sub1 n)))))
```

This `define` form allows extra type annotations for communicating with Typed Racket's typechecker. Without being able to override core forms in a `#lang`, it wouldn't be possible to seamlessly add type annotations.