# memoize is slower when there are multiple parameters

Tags: racket

I found a general memoization from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170706/is-there-a-valid-usecase-for-redefining-define-in-scheme-racket), which makes `fib` much faster by

```
(define (memoize fn)
  (let ((cache (make-hash)))
    (λ arg (hash-ref! cache arg (thunk (apply fn arg))))))

(define fib
  (memoize
   (lambda (n)
     (if (< n 2) n (+ (fib (sub1 n)) (fib (- n 2)))))))
```

I tried to implement the [interleaving string](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-string-is-an-interleaving-of-two-other-given-strings/) question in Racket in natural recursion as

```
(define (is-interleave-rec s1 s2 s3)
  (if (eq? (+ (string-length s1) (string-length s2))
           (string-length s3))
      (aux-rec s1 0 s2 0 s3 0)
      #f))

(define (aux-rec s1 p1 s2 p2 s3 p3)
  (cond
    [(eq? p3 (string-length s3)) #t]
    [(eq? p1 (string-length s1))
     (equal? (substring s2 p2) (substring s3 p3))]
    [(eq? p2 (string-length s2))
     (equal? (substring s1 p1) (substring s3 p3))]
    [(and (eq? (string-ref s1 p1) (string-ref s3 p3))
          (eq? (string-ref s2 p2) (string-ref s3 p3)))
     (or (aux-rec s1 (add1 p1) s2 p2 s3 (add1 p3))
         (aux-rec s1 p1 s2 (add1 p2) s3 (add1 p3)))]
    [(eq? (string-ref s1 p1) (string-ref s3 p3))
     (aux-rec s1 (add1 p1) s2 p2 s3 (add1 p3))]
    [(eq? (string-ref s2 p2) (string-ref s3 p3))
     (aux-rec s1 p1 s2 (add1 p2) s3 (add1 p3))]
    [else #f]))
```

And then a memoization version

```
(define (is-interleave-mem s1 s2 s3)
  (if (eq? (+ (string-length s1) (string-length s2))
           (string-length s3))
      (aux-mem s1 0 s2 0 s3 0)
      #f))

(define aux-mem
  (memoize
   (λ (s1 p1 s2 p2 s3 p3)
     (cond
       [(eq? p3 (string-length s3)) #t]
       [(eq? p1 (string-length s1))
        (equal? (substring s2 p2) (substring s3 p3))]
       [(eq? p2 (string-length s2))
        (equal? (substring s1 p1) (substring s3 p3))]
       [(and (eq? (string-ref s1 p1) (string-ref s3 p3))
             (eq? (string-ref s2 p2) (string-ref s3 p3)))
        (or (aux-mem s1 (add1 p1) s2 p2 s3 (add1 p3))
            (aux-mem s1 p1 s2 (add1 p2) s3 (add1 p3)))]
       [(eq? (string-ref s1 p1) (string-ref s3 p3))
        (aux-mem s1 (add1 p1) s2 p2 s3 (add1 p3))]
       [(eq? (string-ref s2 p2) (string-ref s3 p3))
        (aux-mem s1 p1 s2 (add1 p2) s3 (add1 p3))]
       [else #f]))))
```

To my surprise, the memoization version is slower, testing case was

```
(define as (make-string 10000 #\a))
(define zs (make-string 10000 #\z))
(define bs (make-string 10000 #\b))

(define az (string-append as zs))
(define abz (string-append as bs zs))

(time (is-interleave-rec az bs abz))
(time (is-interleave-mem az bs abz))
```

The result would be

```
cpu time: 4 real time: 4 gc time: 0
#t
cpu time: 5333 real time: 5348 gc time: 67
#t
```

I thought the reason would be there're so many parameters for the hash table, I was wondering if maybe we could improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the code as follows:

```scm
(define allcalls 0)
(define memcalls 0)

(define (memoize fn)
  (let ((cache (make-hash)))
    (λ arg
      (set! allcalls (add1 allcalls))
      (hash-ref! cache arg
                 (thunk
                  (set! memcalls (add1 memcalls))
                  (apply fn arg))))))
```

to track how many times `aux-mem` is called, and how many times it has to call the underlying procedure.

Adding a

```scm
(displayln allcalls)
(displayln memcalls)
```

at the end I get

```scm
cpu time: 2 real time: 2 gc time: 0
#t
cpu time: 7046 real time: 7040 gc time: 30
#t
20001
20001
```

meaning that `aux-mem` is never called twice with the same arguments.

So your memoïzation is totally ineffective (after all, the point of memoïzing is to return a result that has already been asked for and therefore computed earlier) and all it does here is adding overhead.